# tinymce - initially hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am able to create a tinymce editor, and toggling the editor on and off.  Upon initially creation, is there a preferred way to have it hidden (not actually hidden, but editor off and just show the div)?

```
tinymce.init({
    'selector': "#divID"
});

tinymce.editors['divID'].hide();
tinymce.editors['divID'].show();
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114818/hiding-tinymce-with-jquery wont help you?

Comment: @JTC.  No.  It describes the same thing, but uses `tinymce.get('divID').hide();`  For both this way and how I did it, if I put it directly after the script when tinymce is initialized, I get the following errors `TypeError: tinymce.get(...) is undefined` or `tinymce.editors.divIDis undefined`

Comment: thats strange, how do you insert tinymce? with jquery, or by script?

Comment: @JTC.  Script (as shown by my original post).  If I put the hide/show in a click event, it works.  As such, it appears that tinymce takes time to initial, and I am trying to hide it too quick.  I've also tried to hide it within a jquery function thinking it might give it the sufficient time, but no.  Ideally, I would configure it as hidden upon configuration.

Comment: Please see http://jsbin.com/AZIcis/2/.  You will see that the editors are not initially defined, thus the errors.

Comment: Im not sure what seems to be the problem. working for me http://jsfiddle.net/YbFNn/

Comment: @JTC.  jsfiddle isn't real. Try your script on a real webserver.

Comment: I thought adding `'setup' : function(ed) {ed.hide();}` to the initial object might do the trick, but no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I eventually did.  Don't know if there is a better way, but it works.

```
tinymce.init({
    'selector':'#divID',
    setup: function(ed) {
        ed.on('init', function(e) {
            e.target.hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I really am not sure if I understand you right.
Tinymce is an javascript iframe editor, you cant manipulate with it until its full load in page.

You want to show editor on click inside the div?
You could use this `inline` parameter:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "divID",
    inline: true
});
```

[Working example](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php)

You want to hide the editor after some event?
You could use this:

```
$('#bottonID').click(function(){
  tinymce.editors['divID'].hide();
});
```

[Working example](http://jsbin.com/ALAWoSi/1/edit)

Or alternatively, try to use jquery tinymce: 
[download](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)
Then manipulate tinymce like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
    //your code
   });
});
```

If you could be more concrete,what you want to achieve, i could provide more exact answer.

Comment: Thanks JTC.  No, I don't wish to show the editor upon clicking the div, but clicking some other button, so I do not think inline will work.  Yes, I too was able to hide the editor after a click event, but I wanted the editor to be hidden when the page was initially rendered which caused problems.  I did find a solution which I will post.  Thank you for your help.